# Web Storage in Cordova app get carried over even if app is removed

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage

In a Cordova Android app, when I use Web storage (window.localStorage), I notice that sometimes when I uninstall the app (even via `adb uninstall`) and rebuild the app again, window.localStorage stuff appears to get carried over.

This is not just on one Android device, I noticed it several time over different devices.

Is that even possible or is it just the pages got cached?

EDIT:

I created a sample project. And using Cordova 8 and Android platform 7.0.0. Am configuring it right?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:allowBackup="false" />
            <application android:fullBackupContent="false" />
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android 6+ automatically does backup of the data and it's restored when you install the app again.

You can disable it by adding this to the config.xml

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml"
             target="/manifest/application"
             mode="merge">
    <application android:allowBackup="false"/>
    <application android:fullBackupContent="false"/>
</edit-config>
```

That makes the app build fail, you have to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the config.xml widget to make it build.

Comment: Does this work on Cordova 7.1.0? It throws me an unbound prefix error.

Comment: Yeah, I've just tried on a new app created with Cordova CLI 7.1.0 and it worked fine. What's the error you get?

Comment: @huggie the unbound prefix might be caused by socialsharing plugin, try downgrading to a previous version

Comment: I create a new hello world project and it still has the same error. Android platform 6.3.0. I put it within `<platform name="android"></platform>` and I tried placing it outside. It still didn't work for me.

Comment: And you only added that without any other plugin?

Comment: That's right. I didn't add any plugin. I check it now and the one that got automatically included was `cordova-plugin-whitelist`.

Comment: Interesting. What's your node and npm versions?

Comment: I updated node, npm, cordova all to the latest version and create a new sample project. Still the same error. I edit the original question and added config. Am I putting the config in the wrong place?

Comment: I've just copy/pasted your config.xml in a new project I created, ran `cordova prepare` and everything worked fine. Can you publish your sample project on github?

Comment: Ah, I was only checking that the AndroidManifest.xml was being edited, but didn't try to run the app, that's when your error appears. To fix it change your config.xml from `<widget id="com.example.hello" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">` to `<widget id="com.example.hello" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`

Comment: Whah! It works! Thank you for so much patience for going through this with me. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't work on my old project though. That namespace is gone from the XML when I try to build it.

Comment: jcesarmobile, The android namespace gets overwritten in my original project, so it still doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: Are you putting it in the root config.xml?

Comment: Yes the root one, not aware there is any other.

Comment: People sometimes edit the one on platforms/android and complain about it being rewritten. Do the existing project use a different platform version? maybe it was a bug and was fixed in a newer version.

Comment: I created a new project with Android platform 6.4.0 and it work just fine, whereas mine original platform uses 6.4.0 doesn't. Is it possible that some plugin did something to to it?

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. Earlier I was missing to add xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"