# Cordova config.xml xmlns:android namespace gets erased in every build

Tags: android, cordova

Earlier I asked this question.

[Web Storage in Cordova app get carried over even if app is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209494/web-storage-in-cordova-app-get-carried-over-even-if-app-is-removed)

The solution works for a HelloWorld sample project; however, on my existing project, everytime I do a `cordova build` my android xml name space (xmlns:android) is gone and I'll get an unbound prefix error. Any idea?

Comment: If it's erased by cordova, maybe you can try to add a hook to re-add the namespace (maybe a pre-build hook?)

Comment: I checkout hooks, and it looks like it needs to be a script? So are you suggesting using a script to edit that config file?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The idea is to have code to add your namespace after cordova removed it. It's quite easy, you can find the right syntax by looking at scripts in cordova plugins or in cordova framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact issue, the easy resolution is running a cordova clean before running any ionic build etc again.

1. Add your `xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"` to the widget tag in [project root]/config.xml
2. Run cordova clean, then any ionic command, ie `cordova clean; ionic cordova build android`

You'll be able to see it maintains the tag you added in config.xml